# Profiles ordering in migration from Spring Boot 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I’m migrating an application from Spring Boot 2.3 to Spring Boot 2.4, I have some problems with profiles order loading.

In my application, I have some profiles :

- default (*application-default.yml*) : default values for the application. There is a lot of default values, the goal is not to complicate the file application.yml, **so it's very important to have this file**
- quality (*application-quality.yml*) : quality profile
- environment profile (for example *application-Dev.yml*) : profile of the current environment. It must override application.yml and application-default.yml values
- database profile for the environment (for example application-databaseDev.yml) : profile for the database connection for the current environment

In Spring Boot 2.3, configuration is :

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - default
  redis:
    jedis:
      pool:
        max-active: 4
```

*application-default.yml*

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - quality
myApplication:
  vcs:
    url: https://default.url 
  cache:
    enabled: true
```

*application-Dev.yml*

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include:
      - databaseDev
myApplication:
  cache:
    enabled: false
```

I'm starting application with parameter `--spring.profiles.active=Dev`

In this case, here is the order of the active profile `The following profiles are active: default,quality,Dev,databaseDev`

> This is order I want. For exemple value for key *myApplication.cache.enabled* is *false*

I read the documentation to migrate to Spring Boot 2.4, so my configuration is now :

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      "Dev": "default, quality, databaseDev"
  redis:
    jedis:
      pool:
        max-active: 4
```

*application-default.yml*

```
myApplication:
  vcs:
    url: https://default.url 
  cache:
    enabled: true
```

*application-Dev.yml*

```
myApplication:
  cache:
    enabled: false
```

But now I have the active profile `The following profiles are active: Dev,default,quality,databaseDev`

> In this case the value for key *myApplication.cache.enabled* is *true*

Now profile *Dev* doesn't override *default* profile as 2.3 but inversely *default* profile override *Dev* profile.

Is there a way to modify the configuration to work as 2.3 (without using `use-legacy-processing: true`)? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works :
Rename the profile `Dev` to `dev` and create a group named `Dev`

Here is the result :

*application.yml*

```
spring:
  config:
    import: classpath:application-groups.yml 
  redis:
    jedis:
      pool:
        max-active: 4
```

*application-groups.yml*

```
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      "base": "default, quality"
      "Dev": "base, databaseDev"
```

*application-default.yml*

```
myApplication:
  vcs:
    url: https://default.url 
  cache:
    enabled: true
```

*application-dev.yml*

```
myApplication:
  cache:
    enabled: false
```

Starting with parameter `--spring.profiles.active=Dev`
`The following profiles are active: Dev,base,default,quality,databaseDev`

What do you think about this solution ?

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. `application-dev.yml` never gets used.